# Difference between longitudinal data and panel data

Tags: time-series, panel-data, terminology

When trying to grasp the terminology behind some time-series concepts, I have came across [Rob Hyndman's article](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/terminology-matters/) which states the following

> Econometricians use “panel data” while statisticians use “longitudinal
> data” to refer to collections of time series.

After searching (check the search done bellow), I end up with the idea that the concepts are the same.

Is the fields that the terms are being used the only difference between longitudinal data and panel data?

---

### Search

1. **Longitudinal data**:

1.1. [This blog entry](https://blog.stata.com/2013/02/18/multilevel-linear-models-in-stata-part-2-longitudinal-data/) defines it as

> Longitudinal data typically arise from collecting a few observations
> over time from many sources, such as a few blood pressure measurements
> from many people.

1.2. [This article](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-73251-0_11) defines it as

> Then longitudinal analysis is the study of collections of variables;
> in most applications the variables are strongly associated.  We can
> associate each time point with a separate variable, in the spirit of
> the original definition of the term variable.

2. **Panel**:

2.1. [This article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9781118901731.iecrm0134) it looks like Panel Analysis is the same as Longitudinal Analysis

> Longitudinal or panel data analysis refers to the statistical analysis
> of pooled data which consists of a cross‐section of units (e.g.,
> countries, firms, households, individuals) for which there exist
> repeated observations over time.

2.2. [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panel_data) goes within the same line as the article in 2.1.

> In statistics and econometrics, panel data and longitudinal data
> are both multi-dimensional data involving measurements over time.

2.3. [This Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-time-series-analysis-and-longitudinal-data-analysis) use the terms interchangeably

> longitudinal or panel data, observations of multiple phenomena over
> multiple time periods for the same data units;  involves repeated
> observations of the same variables (e.g., people) over periods of
> time;  can prove cause and effect, but time-consuming and expensive

Comment: @ G. Peres I appreciate your well researched question! In extension to @markowitz's response I would add that the focus should be on the purpose for which the data were collected and the results sought. I would leave the rest to semantics.

Answer (score 7):

Longitudinal and panel data are synonym. There are only three possibility:

1. cross section: several variable one time only
2. time series: one variable only measured many times
3. panel/longitudinal: several variables measured several times

Moreover note that, at least in econometrics, the fact that we have a panel dataset do not imply that we must use models for panel data. For example a simple VAR (vector autoregression) is a typical time series model and do not represent a panel data technique, even if the dataset would be suitable for.

Comment: By "several variables" you mean "several units"? Like households, persons, families?

Answer (score 0):

Longitudinal data refer to repetitive measurements over time. The measurement could be on the same units or otherwise. Panel data are a type of longitudinal data where the observed units are the same. Repeated cross-sections are longitudinal but can hardly be considered panel, at least in econometric modelling.